# Sending signals between three threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I had to write a program that uses 3 threads - one to read letters, second to count characters, and the third to output them. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

int first[2];
int second[2];

void *input(void *ptr)
{
   char str[100];
   int length;

   while(1)
   {
      printf("Enter the message: ");
      fflush(stdout);
      length = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof(str));

      if(str[0] == ';')
         exit(2);

      if(length <= 0)
      {
         if(length == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[1]);
         exit(2);
      }

      if(write(first[1], str, length) != length)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }
   }
}

void *countChars(void *ptr)
{
   char str[100];
   int length, count = 0;

   while(1)
   {
      length = read(first[0], str, sizeof(str));
      if(length <= 0)
      {
         if(length == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[0]);
         close(second[1]);
         exit(2);
      }
      if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, length) != length)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }

      while(str[count] != '\n') count++;

      write(second[1], &count, sizeof(count));

      count = 0;
   }
}

void *output(void *ptr)
{
   int length, count = 0;

   while(1)
   {
      length = read(second[0], &count, sizeof(count));
      if(length < sizeof(count))
      {
         close(second[0]);
         exit(2);
      }

      printf("Number of characters: %d\n", count);
   }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t t1, t2, t3;

   if(pipe(first) == -1)
   {
      printf("First pipe error");
      exit(1);
   }

   if(pipe(second) == -1)
   {
      printf("Second pipe error");
      exit(1);
   }

   pthread_create(&t1, NULL, input, NULL);
   pthread_create(&t2, NULL, countChars, NULL);
   pthread_create(&t3, NULL, output, NULL);

   pthread_join(t1, NULL);
   pthread_join(t2, NULL);
   pthread_join(t3, NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

It works, but right now I have to implement signals here. Sending SIGUSR1 signal should stop program execution until sending SIGUSR2 signal.

The problem is that when I send the signal, only one thread gets it. And thus I have to use FIFO to inform other threads which signal was executed and execute it in the rest of them.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals are delivered to the process, not to the threads.  Thus any thread that is able to handle a signal may be used to call a signal handler.  What you need to do is figure out how to handle the signal and then decide how to communicate that to all the threads.  You have not really described what you mean by "stop program execution", so I'll have to guess.

I would suggest using a combination of `pthread_sigmask` and `sigwait`.  You can use `pthread_sigmask` to disable automatic handling of SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 in your worker threads. Then call `sigwait` in a fourth signal handler thread to explicitly handle those signals.  When the signal handler thread receives a SIGUSR1 it sets a global flag.  The worker threads check that flag periodically and go to sleep (on a condition variable maybe?) when it is set.  The signal handler thread then loops around and calls `sigwait` again.  When it receives a SIGUSR2, it wakes up the worker threads, then loops around and calls `sigwait`, once again.